# When should forms be cleaned?

Tags: forms, user-interface, user-experience

By "cleaned" I mean formatting inputs such as "a1b2c3" into "A1B 2C3" or "5551234567" into "(555) 123-4567". I figure we have few options:

1. **As the user is typing.** For instance, when a user is typing a postal code, all letters are instantly capitalized, or after the user types 3 digits of a phone number, it puts brackets around them.
2. **When the field loses focus.**
3. **Never.** Formatting happens on the server-side only, just before it is inserted into the DB. The user never gets to see how it was formatted unless it is displayed on the site somewhere.
   (3b) **If there were form errors, or on the confirmation page.** If there are form errors and the form needs to be re-displayed, the formatting on the valid inputs will appear, or if you have a confirmation page (are these inputs correct?) they will show there.
4. **Never ever.** Data should be dumped into the database as-is and only formatted in the template/view just before it is displayed back to the user.

What do you think? I think I like (2). Reminds me of how code-formatting works in Visual Studio (happens when you close a brace or type a semi-colon).

Comment: It really depends on what kind of data it is, what it represents, and what it's going to be used for, doesn't it?

Comment: no need to discuss on these type of questions. formatting only needs when your client ask that. formating also differ based on country, based on what you are formating , zip , phone , height or weight :). Client side format is needed . Otherwise user will enter anything and server cant handle that properly. add one more option there 5. do formatting when your boss (client) says to format .  :)

Comment: @zod: "otherwise the user will enter anything" -- that's called validation; this is a separate issue. (5) only applies if your only goal is to collect a paycheque; some of us take pride in our work.

Comment: @Pekka: How so? If it's data that has a standard format, I think it should be coerced into that format. Or at least, a consistent format to make querying and converting easier. For example, times should be converted to a consistent timezone, then you can convert it to whatever timezone you like, perhaps based on the user's region. Phone numbers might be formatted differently in different regions, but at least if you save it consistently, you can deal with regional differences later. When is consistency ever bad? Makes querying easier.

Comment: Why you are talking about paycheque!!  i was talking about client. You can do a website for charity. If you add your own standard and your own format you can use it. If you are doing a website of a charity institution from asia, you have to use their standards in time , currency, phone number, zip code. Think Global :)

Comment: @zod: That's called localization... of course you should format it for the target demographic, but we're talking about when/where you should do it, not what format :) And so what if it's for charity? That means you should do a shoddy job because they're not paying you?

Comment: @Mark I maintain this entirely depends. On the target format. On audience and user expectations. On the kind of devices it is used on. On how the data will be used. Etc. etc. Either of the five options can be the best one in a different situation, so I don't see the point in a generalization

Comment: @Pekka: Fair enough, I see your point now. Let me clarify then: for a North American demographic, ages 20-70, mostly receptionist or secretary-type people, mostly desktop computers running Windows XP or later, internet explorer. That's who I suspect my target audience will be.

Comment: @Mark an additional suggestion: 2b.) upon clicking a "Validate input" or "Check input" button. If user input is changed by the system (e.g. a zip code turned into a place name, or a phone number converted into full format) this gives the user a means to check whether the change was correct. Changing contents during input I find generally okay if it's only uppercasing or lowercasing, but any format change should take place afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to either filter the field just after it loses focus (when it is critical that the field be formatted correctly before they move on to the next field - which is rarely), or I filter the field content as soon as the user hits the "SUBMIT" button (or whatever you want to call it) to send the data to the server.

This has a few advantages for me:

1. The user's input is not interrupted with annoying "auto-corrections" - being auto-corrected can sometimes feel like demonic possession if it is not done well.
2. The user really neither cares, nor needs to know that you do not want the (,), or -, in your phone number field... so take it out quietly for them. No notes, or instructions needed.
3. Also, I ALWAYS filter the field values anyway to protect against any kind of code-injection attacks (which are alarmingly easy to pull off if you know what you are doing). I have read about entire databases being compromised because the author did not remove potential SQL markup from submitted data.... it makes me shudder.
4. It also allows me to check for ALL input errors (if any), or non-filled-out required fields and report a single set of issues to the user at a single time... I have been to sites that give you so many messages while filling out a form it feels a bit like having a nagging relative over your shoulder.

Comment: Me, too. I try to keep my forms as easy to complete as possible without punishing the user. (:)-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with either (1) or (2), depending on the kind of input. (1) is probably most user-friendly if done right, but it will be more complex to implement neatly (e.g., what happens if I delete a digit from a hyphenated phone number - or a hyphen?). Go with (1) if you can afford it, otherwise (2).

Comment: Yeah...that's the other issue with (1). I don't like it because it's tricky to implement, and from a user-perspective, perhaps a bit confusing. I don't like when sites mess with my input before I'm even done typing it.

Comment: For what it's worth, reformatting when the field loses focus may also be confusing. The user may spend time reformatting the string manually, unaware that the software is ready to do that for him. I personally prefer on-the-fly formatting, as long as it is reliable and foolproof.

Comment: Good point, but he'll probably learn quickly after he enters one input. It's a member-site anyway, we expect repeat customers. They'll get used to my forms, whether they like it or not ;)

Answer (score 1):

I follow the same method I use for validation. Once on the client side, once on the server side. Whether it happens on loose focus or as they type it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I don't think consistency matters in that respect as long as it happens. (1) and (2) on different controls in the same form would be fine. I mean, how are you going to fix as you type for a user entering a date in a DD-MMM-YYYY format?

Comment: But yeah, don't forget to format again on DB insert, update, etc, you don't want some ass sending raw http posts with junk data to mess up your database.

Answer (score 0):

> As the user is typing. For instance, when a user is typing a postal code, all letters are instantly capitalized, or after the user types 3 digits of a phone number, it puts brackets around them.

This type of input is excellent for things such as entering serial codes or CD keys for software or games. I notice a lot of people get confused whether or not the code is case sensitive or if they should be inputting the dashes as well.

If you have an iPhone you'll notice when entering a phone number it is also auto formatted with brackets and spaces as you enter it. But this often turns out to be confusing as a partially typed number is not always 'grouped' correctly.

Answer: It all depends on context.